# Clone MongoDB objects in Meteorjs by changing value of a single field

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongoid, meteorite

I am working on a Meteorjs application which is using MongoDB in back end.
In my collection there are some objects which are having a common field named `parent_id` eg

```js
{name:'A',parent_id:'acd'}
{name:'b',parent_id:'acd'}
{name:'c',parent_id:'acd'}
{name:'d',parent_id:'acd'}
```

I want to copy all these objects in the database by changing the `parent_id` field eg

```js
{name:'A',parent_id:'acdef'}
{name:'b',parent_id:'acdef'}
{name:'c',parent_id:'acdef'}
{name:'d',parent_id:'acdef'}
```

and these all objects will be in database like this

```js
{name:'A',parent_id:'acd'}
{name:'b',parent_id:'acd'}
{name:'c',parent_id:'acd'}
{name:'d',parent_id:'acd'}
{name:'A',parent_id:'acdef'}
{name:'b',parent_id:'acdef'}
{name:'c',parent_id:'acdef'}
{name:'d',parent_id:'acdef'}
```

for this I have find the elements from the db which have parent_id:'abc'
    items=db.collection.find({parent_id:'abc').fetch()
and using a loop i have changed the parent_id of each item and then tried this command

```js
for(i=0;i<items.length;i++){
    items[i].parent_id='abcdef';
    meteor.collection.insert(item)
}
```

but it is giving me an error`duplicate for _id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it will unless you **delete** the `_id` value from the object first:

```js
for(i=0;i<items.length;i++){
    items[i].parent_id='abcdef';
    delete items[i]["_id"];
    meteor.collection.insert(item[i])
}
```

So the **delete** should clear that up and an **new** `_id` will be generated.

Answer (score 1):

When you `Collection.find()` your documents you can use the field specifier to exclude the `_id` field.

```js
var items = collection.find({}, {fields: {name: 1, parent_id: 1, _id: 0}).fetch();
```

Then when you modify and insert those documents again, they will be duplicates with each having its own unique `_id`.